# Can selenium grid 2.0 hub also act as node?

Tags: selenium-grid

Can a selenium grid 2.0 hub also act as a node?

I ask because I want to cut-down on the cost of buying another node. It would be great to have the hub also do some node work.

Answer (score 0):

Sure it can and this is most commonly used method as well.
You just need to make sure to use 2 separate ports on the machine for hub and node.

I suggest not to configure more than 2 instances of browsers on an average power machine, otherwise you might see test failures due to grid performance.